# WCF custom binding - Content Type not supported by service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wcf-binding

I have defined a custom binding in my client and server web.config file, but when I try to connect I get this error, 
server is running IIS 7

Content Type application/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost/contentservice.svc/PairService.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

**Server:**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint binding="customBinding"  bindingConfiguration="BinaryBinding" contract="Me.IContentService" name="ContentStagingEndpoint" />
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="BinaryBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ContentService">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ContentService" name="Me.ContentService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"  bindingConfiguration="BinaryBinding" contract="Contracts.IContentService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="BinaryBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and here is the code that initiates the call:

```
var chan = New WebChannelFactory(Of IContentService)(New Uri("http://localhost/contentservice.svc")).CreateChannel();

chan.PairService();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,
I had to use `ChannelFactory` instead of `WebChannelFactory`

```
var proxy =  ChannelFactory(Of IContentService).CreateChannel(New EndpointAddress("http://localhost/service.svc"))
```